# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.<init> exception

Tags: apache-curator

> INFO [2020-02-10 07:03:32,933]
>   curator.utils.Compatibility:[Compatibility::48] - [main] -
>   Running in ZooKeeper 3.4.x compatibility mode INFO [2020-02-10
>   07:03:32,934] curator.utils.Compatibility:[Compatibility::61]
>   - [main] - Using emulated InjectSessionExpiration Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.(Lorg/apache/curator/utils/ZookeeperFactory;Lorg/apache/curator/ensemble/EnsembleProvider;IIILorg/apache/zookeeper/Watcher;Lorg/apache/curator/RetryPolicy;ZLorg/apache/curator/connection/ConnectionHandlingPolicy;)V
>     at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFrameworkFactory$Builder.build(CuratorFrameworkFactory.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(CuratorFrameworkFactory.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(CuratorFrameworkFactory.java:94)
>     at
>   com.vnera.common.utils.DistributedSemaphore$CuratorFrameworkWrapper.(DistributedSemaphore.java:166)
>     at
>   com.vnera.common.utils.DistributedSemaphore.create(DistributedSemaphore.java:65)
>     at
>   com.vnera.tools.DistributedSemaphoreTestTool.main(DistributedSemaphoreTestTool.java:86)

Isn't curator 4.2 compatible with zookeepr 3.4.x?
Any pointers?

Comment: What is "DistributedSemaphore"? You may have code in that class that assumes ZooKeeper 3.5.x

Comment: DistributedSemaphore* are my classes. Think of them as wrappers over curator abstractions.

Comment: Also - looks like some code is compiled against a different version of Curator? It's hard to read that stacktrace. Anyway, do a dependency tree with your build tool and I'll bet the problem is there.

Comment: Turned out a dependency issue. Fixed and working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

It is but you need to make sure your dependencies are correct. Please see the doc here: https://curator.apache.org/zk-compatibility.html

You need to:

- Exclude the transitive dependency to ZooKeeper in your Curator dependency statement (the doc has examples for both Gradle and Maven)
- Add a hard dependency to ZooKeeper 3.4.x